# Difference in loading via the spl_autoload_register

Tags: php, include, require, require-once, spl-autoload-register

I have three files

/autoload-test.php

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/controllers/' . $class . '.php');
});
$different_file_obj = new test;
```

/controllers/test.php

```
require_once('some_var.php');
class test {
        function __construct() {
                echo $GLOBALS['var'];
            }
    }
```

/controllers/some_var.php

```
$var = 'some value';
```

When I open the file 1 in browser it gives me this ->
Notice: Undefined index: var in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/avrs/controllers/test.php on line 7

But if I change the file to ->

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/controllers/test.php');
$different_file_obj = new test;
```

It works fine, so I am thinking that there is some difference in including the file using the spl_autoload_register, because that is the only thing that I am changing here. Including with out the spl_autoload_register works absolutely fine.

Is there something I should know or some where I can read in details about this?

Comment: Do you really want to use global variables in this way?

Comment: I have used global variables like this in my entire project. Is this not the correct way to do it?

Comment: No, global variables are evil, they limit code reuse and testability, and hide the real information flow in your code. You can use them, but everybody else that gets in contact with your code will curse you because of them. Note that you can avoid having such configuration include files: `return 'some_value';` and `$var = require('some_var.php');` works, and you can directly pass the value into the constructor, store it in an object variable, and use that instead.

Comment: Why global variables are considered evil?

Comment: If you look at the code of a function, that function uses `$var` (a global variable), then calls another function, and continues to use `$var` - what do you expect? Is `$var` still the same after that function call, or did it change? I would like so say it's the same. But if you say "changed", you have looked at the code of that other function that was called. And that is the evil part: To be sure what happens you must look at ALL the code! If you only look at one part of the code, you do know everything WITHOUT globals - but anything can happen when globals are used.